# Mystifying UB/segfault only on gcc - is the code ill-formed?

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior, c++17

```
#include <utility>

template <typename P, typename F>
struct foo
{
    P _p;
    int i{0};

    foo(P&& p, F) : _p{std::move(p)} { }

    template <typename... Cs>
    void up(Cs&... cs)
    {
        if constexpr(sizeof...(Cs) == 2) { down(cs...); }
        else { _p.up(*this, cs...); }
    }

    void down() { --i; }

    template <typename C, typename... Cs>
    void down(C& c, Cs&... cs)
    {
        [&] { [&] { c.down(cs...); }(); }();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto f = foo{foo{foo{0, 0}, 0}, 0};
    f.up();
}
```

The code snippet above:

- Always segfaults on execution when compiled with g++ 7.1 and trunk, with `-O0`.
- Always reports errors on execution when compiled with g++ 7.1 and trunk, with any optimization level and either `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined`.
- Never segfaults or report any sanitizer error with clang++ 5 and trunk.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/C37Y6fWCTCfnalCR)

---

Taking any of the following actions:

- Getting rid of `--i;` from `down()`.
- Changing `[&] { [&] { c.down(cs...); }(); }();` to `[&] { c.down(cs...); }();`.
- Removing `typename F` and updating the constructor accordingly.
- Changing `foo{foo{foo{0, 0}, 0}, 0}` to `foo{foo{0, 0}, 0}`.

Fixes the segmentation fault and prevents any sanitizer error.

What's going on here? **Is my code ill-formed, or is this a weird gcc bug that produces wrong assembly?**

Comment: Can't compile this code. And it differs from the one on Wandbox.

Comment: @ks1322: fixed the link, sorry.

Comment: How are you updating the `foo{foo{foo{0, 0}, 0}, 0}` after you get rid of `typename F`? If you just remove the second argument you'll get a completely different deduction.

Comment: In any event, obvious bug is obvious. This has something to do with nested default lambda captures. Explicitly capturing `c` and `cs...` at either layer fixes the sanitizer error.

Comment: This is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79180